# Creating new AppDomain in F# Interactive

Tags: .net, wpf, f#, f#-interactive

I need the ability to create a new AppDomain in F# interactive in order to host multiple WPF applications. I don't have any problem getting the necessary functionality to work in a compiled F# application, but for some reason getting it to work in F# interactive doesn't seem to be possible.

Here is the simplest possible case:-

```
#r "PresentationCore.dll"
#r "PresentationFramework.dll"
#r "System.Xaml.dll"
#r "WindowsBase.dll"

open System    
open System.Threading
open System.Windows

type myClass() = 
    let domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("another domain")

    //this function starts a WPF app
    let funct() =                
        let WPFStart() =
            let app = Application()
            let win = Window()            
            app.Run(win) |> ignore
        let thread = Thread WPFStart
        thread.IsBackground <- true
        thread.SetApartmentState ApartmentState.STA
        thread.Start()

    do CrossAppDomainDelegate(funct) |> domain.DoCallBack

myClass();;
```

I always get back something along the lines of

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type is not resolved 
for member 'FSI_0002+-ctor@24,FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
at FSI_0002.myClass..ctor()
at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

What do I need to do to get this to work in F# interactive?

Comment: You mean in the F# Interactive window in Visual Studio?

Comment: I recall fighting with this at some point - I tried a few ideas, but none of them worked, so I think it might not be easily possible to do this.

Comment: To pass delegate thru `AppDomain` boundary it need to be serialized on one side and deserialized on another side. `MethodInfo` object serialized as assembly name, type name, method name and signature. Since your method effectively defined in dynamic assembly, which does not present on disk, receiving `AppDomain` can not load it by merely assembly name, thus it can not deserialize delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intro from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/fsharp-interactive/):

> F# Interactive attempts to compile the code and, if successful, it executes the code and prints the signature of the types and values that it compiled.

The main gotcha lies in the compilation step

```
typeof<myClass>.Assembly.FullName
```

Output:

> ```
> val it : string =
>   "FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
> ```

In order to compile the code *fsi* uses a dynamic assembly to host all types created during a session. The key element here is that other domains won't be able to resolve these types without a reference to that containing assembly. However, getting a hold of the assembly from other app domains proves to be non-trivial. Mainly because we're dealing with a dynamic assembly.

```
let asm = typeof<myClass>.Assembly 
asm.IsDynamic // val it : bool = true
```

Meaning, it only exists in memory of *fsi*'s default appdomain. Both lookups below throw

> System.NotSupportedException: The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly.

```
asm.Location
asm.CodeBase
```

Typically, you'd want to persist to disk first, ref [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) - *Restrictions on emitting to remote application domains*:

> Some scenarios require a dynamic assembly to be created and executed in a remote application domain. Reflection emit does not allow a dynamic assembly to be emitted directly to a remote application domain. The solution is to emit the dynamic assembly in the current application domain, save the emitted dynamic assembly to disk, and then load the dynamic assembly into the remote application domain.

Successfully casting the dynamic assembly to `AssemblyBuilder` would expose a `Save` method. Unfortunately, this workflow has been sealed off as well.

```
open System.Reflection.Emit
let builder = asm :?> AssemblyBuilder
```

Throws

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.Emit.InternalAssemblyBuilder' to type 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder'

We're dealing with an internal type, clearly we're not ment to get our hands dirty. From [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/assemblybuilder.cs,0a02dd04589d9b5b):

> In the past, when InternalAssemblyBuilder was AssemblyBuilder, the untrusted user could down cast the Assembly to an AssemblyBuilder and emit code with the elevated permissions of the trusted code which origionally created the AssemblyBuilder via DefineDynamicAssembly. Today, this can no longer happen because the Assembly returned via AssemblyGetAssemblies() will be an InternalAssemblyBuilder.

Alternatively, you could reflect over the types in the dynamic assembly and [reconstruct them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) using a `new AssemblyBuilder` and other helpers in the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace, but it all seems a tad on the tedious side.

To conclude, the way it's currently implemented you'll be swimming against the stream trying to expose *fsi* generated types to other domains.